# How to use GPU for object detection in tensorflow app for a tflite model?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-lite

I have created a android application which can detect road cracks in realtime using yolov5n model. This model gives inference of upto 120-150ms on cpu, but when i test this app on roads by mounting it on a vechile at a speed of 30km/hr it is unable to detect road cracks. So i wanted to reduce its inference to less than 100ms by making the app run on gpu.

I have used tensorflow lite example app for android:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

Here is my application code:
https://github.com/Lucifer7535/RCD

In the Yolov5Classifier.java file at 227th line i changed the value of

```
private static boolean isGPU = false;
```

from false to true. (so that i can use gpu)

But Getting these errors:

```
CameraActivity: onCreate com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.DetectorActivity@6f69478
BottomSheetBehavior now supports multiple callbacks. `setBottomSheetCallback()` removes all existing callbacks, including ones set internally by library authors, which may result in unintended behavior. This may change in the future. Please use `addBottomSheetCallback()` and `removeBottomSheetCallback()` instead to set your own callbacks.
CameraActivity: onStart com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.DetectorActivity@6f69478
CameraActivity: onResume com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.DetectorActivity@6f69478
CameraActivity: onPause com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.DetectorActivity@6f69478
Connecting to camera service
[soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 2
[soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 3
CameraActivity: Camera API lv2?: true
CameraActivity: onResume com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.DetectorActivity@6f69478
CameraConnectionFragment: Desired size: 640x640, min size: 640x640
CameraConnectionFragment: Valid preview sizes: [4000x3000, 4000x2250, 3840x2160, 2592x1944, 2592x1940, 2048x1536, 1920x1080, 1600x1200, 1440x1080, 1440x720, 1280x960, 1280x768, 1280x720]
CameraConnectionFragment: Rejected preview sizes: [1280x480, 1280x400, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 480x640, 480x360, 480x320, 352x288, 320x240, 240x320, 176x144, 144x176]
CameraConnectionFragment: Chosen size: 1280x720
YoloV5Classifier: Linear crack
YoloV5Classifier: Transverse crack
YoloV5Classifier: Alligator crack
YoloV5Classifier: Pothole
Created TensorFlow Lite delegate for GPU.
Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
Replacing 386 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) node, yielding 1 partitions.
"/vendor/lib64/libCB.so" has invalid shdr offset/size: 2770720/1536
<clGetPlatformIDs:2422>: Fatal: Failed to open libCB from libOpenCL
call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
Initialized OpenGL-based API.
Created 0 GPU delegate kernels.
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector, PID: 16188
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: clGetPlatformIDs returned -30
Falling back to OpenGL
TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: Add does not support HWC constant tensor
TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: delegate is not initialized
Node number 386 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to prepare.
Restored original execution plan after delegate application failure.
at com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.tflite.YoloV5Classifier.create(YoloV5Classifier.java:101)
... 70 more
```

Although it runs perfectly on CPU. So how can i fix this? Please help

Here is the code for Yolov5Classifier.java

```
package com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.tflite;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;

import com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.LoginActivity;
import com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.MainActivity;
import com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.env.Logger;
import com.gvvp.roadcrackdetector.env.Utils;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;
import org.tensorflow.lite.nnapi.NnApiDelegate;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Vector;


/**
 * Wrapper for frozen detection models trained using the Tensorflow Object Detection API:
 * - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
 * where you can find the training code.
 * <p>
 * To use pretrained models in the API or convert to TF Lite models, please see docs for details:
 * - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md
 * - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md#running-our-model-on-android
 */
public class YoloV5Classifier implements Classifier {

    /**
     * Initializes a native TensorFlow session for classifying images.
     *
     * @param assetManager  The asset manager to be used to load assets.
     * @param modelFilename The filepath of the model GraphDef protocol buffer.
     * @param labelFilename The filepath of label file for classes.
     * @param isQuantized   Boolean representing model is quantized or not
     */
    public static YoloV5Classifier create(
            final AssetManager assetManager,
            final String modelFilename,
            final String labelFilename,
            final boolean isQuantized,
            final int inputSize
            /*final int[] output_width,
            final int[][] masks,
            final int[] anchors*/)
            throws IOException {
        final YoloV5Classifier d = new YoloV5Classifier();

        String actualFilename = labelFilename.split("file:///android_asset/")[1];
        InputStream labelsInput = assetManager.open(actualFilename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(labelsInput));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            LOGGER.w(line);
            d.labels.add(line);
        }
        br.close();

        try {
            Interpreter.Options options = (new Interpreter.Options());
            options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
            if (isNNAPI) {
                d.nnapiDelegate = null;
                // Initialize interpreter with NNAPI delegate for Android Pie or above
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    d.nnapiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate();
                    options.addDelegate(d.nnapiDelegate);
                    options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
//                    options.setUseNNAPI(false);
//                    options.setAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(true);
//                    options.setAllowBufferHandleOutput(true);
                    options.setUseNNAPI(true);
                }
            }
            if (isGPU) {
                GpuDelegate.Options gpu_options = new GpuDelegate.Options();
                gpu_options.setPrecisionLossAllowed(true); // It seems that the default is true
                gpu_options.setInferencePreference(GpuDelegate.Options.INFERENCE_PREFERENCE_SUSTAINED_SPEED);
                d.gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate(gpu_options);
                options.addDelegate(d.gpuDelegate);
            }
            d.tfliteModel = Utils.loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename);
            d.tfLite = new Interpreter(d.tfliteModel, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        d.isModelQuantized = isQuantized;
        // Pre-allocate buffers.
        int numBytesPerChannel;
        if (isQuantized) {
            numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
        } else {
            numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
        }
        d.INPUT_SIZE = inputSize;
        d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.INPUT_SIZE * d.INPUT_SIZE * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
        d.imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        d.intValues = new int[d.INPUT_SIZE * d.INPUT_SIZE];

        d.output_box = (int) ((Math.pow((inputSize / 32), 2) + Math.pow((inputSize / 16), 2) + Math.pow((inputSize / 8), 2)) * 3);
//        d.OUTPUT_WIDTH = output_width;
//        d.MASKS = masks;
//        d.ANCHORS = anchors;
        if (d.isModelQuantized){
            Tensor inpten = d.tfLite.getInputTensor(0);
            d.inp_scale = inpten.quantizationParams().getScale();
            d.inp_zero_point = inpten.quantizationParams().getZeroPoint();
            Tensor oupten = d.tfLite.getOutputTensor(0);
            d.oup_scale = oupten.quantizationParams().getScale();
            d.oup_zero_point = oupten.quantizationParams().getZeroPoint();
        }

        int[] shape = d.tfLite.getOutputTensor(0).shape();
        int numClass = shape[shape.length - 1] - 5;
        d.numClass = numClass;
        d.outData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(d.output_box * (numClass + 5) * numBytesPerChannel);
        d.outData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        return d;
    }

    public int getInputSize() {
        return INPUT_SIZE;
    }
    @Override
    public void enableStatLogging(final boolean logStats) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getStatString() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        tfLite.close();
        tfLite = null;
        if (gpuDelegate != null) {
            gpuDelegate.close();
            gpuDelegate = null;
        }
        if (nnapiDelegate != null) {
            nnapiDelegate.close();
            nnapiDelegate = null;
        }
        tfliteModel = null;
    }

    public void setNumThreads(int num_threads) {
        Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options();
        if (tfLite != null) options.setNumThreads(num_threads);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseNNAPI(boolean isChecked) {
//        if (tfLite != null) tfLite.setUseNNAPI(isChecked);
    }

    private void recreateInterpreter() {
        if (tfLite != null) {
            tfLite.close();
            tfLite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);
        }
    }

    public void useGpu() {
        if (gpuDelegate == null) {
            gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate();
            tfliteOptions.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
            recreateInterpreter();
        }
    }

    public void useCPU() {
        recreateInterpreter();
    }

    public void useNNAPI() {
        nnapiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate();
        tfliteOptions.addDelegate(nnapiDelegate);
        recreateInterpreter();
    }

    @Override
    public float getObjThresh() {
        return MainActivity.MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

    // Float model
    private final float IMAGE_MEAN = 0;

    private final float IMAGE_STD = 255.0f;

    //config yolo
    private int INPUT_SIZE = -1;

//    private int[] OUTPUT_WIDTH;
//    private int[][] MASKS;
//    private int[] ANCHORS;
    private  int output_box;

    private static final float[] XYSCALE = new float[]{1.2f, 1.1f, 1.05f};

    private static final int NUM_BOXES_PER_BLOCK = 3;

    // Number of threads in the java app
    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 1;
    private static boolean isNNAPI = false;
    private static boolean isGPU = true;

    private boolean isModelQuantized;

    /** holds a gpu delegate */
    GpuDelegate gpuDelegate = null;
    /** holds an nnapi delegate */
    NnApiDelegate nnapiDelegate = null;

    /** The loaded TensorFlow Lite model. */
    private MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel;

    /** Options for configuring the Interpreter. */
    private final Interpreter.Options tfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

    // Config values.

    // Pre-allocated buffers.
    private Vector<String> labels = new Vector<String>();
    private int[] intValues;

    private ByteBuffer imgData;
    private ByteBuffer outData;

    private Interpreter tfLite;
    private float inp_scale;
    private int inp_zero_point;
    private float oup_scale;
    private int oup_zero_point;
    private int numClass;
    private YoloV5Classifier() {
    }

    //non maximum suppression
    protected ArrayList<Recognition> nms(ArrayList<Recognition> list) {
        ArrayList<Recognition> nmsList = new ArrayList<Recognition>();

        for (int k = 0; k < labels.size(); k++) {
            //1.find max confidence per class
            PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
                    new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
                            50,
                            new Comparator<Recognition>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(final Recognition lhs, final Recognition rhs) {
                                    // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                                    return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
                                }
                            });

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                if (list.get(i).getDetectedClass() == k) {
                    pq.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            //2.do non maximum suppression
            while (pq.size() > 0) {
                //insert detection with max confidence
                Recognition[] a = new Recognition[pq.size()];
                Recognition[] detections = pq.toArray(a);
                Recognition max = detections[0];
                nmsList.add(max);
                pq.clear();

                for (int j = 1; j < detections.length; j++) {
                    Recognition detection = detections[j];
                    RectF b = detection.getLocation();
                    if (box_iou(max.getLocation(), b) < mNmsThresh) {
                        pq.add(detection);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nmsList;
    }

    protected float mNmsThresh = 0.6f;

    protected float box_iou(RectF a, RectF b) {
        return box_intersection(a, b) / box_union(a, b);
    }

    protected float box_intersection(RectF a, RectF b) {
        float w = overlap((a.left + a.right) / 2, a.right - a.left,
                (b.left + b.right) / 2, b.right - b.left);
        float h = overlap((a.top + a.bottom) / 2, a.bottom - a.top,
                (b.top + b.bottom) / 2, b.bottom - b.top);
        if (w < 0 || h < 0) return 0;
        float area = w * h;
        return area;
    }

    protected float box_union(RectF a, RectF b) {
        float i = box_intersection(a, b);
        float u = (a.right - a.left) * (a.bottom - a.top) + (b.right - b.left) * (b.bottom - b.top) - i;
        return u;
    }

    protected float overlap(float x1, float w1, float x2, float w2) {
        float l1 = x1 - w1 / 2;
        float l2 = x2 - w2 / 2;
        float left = l1 > l2 ? l1 : l2;
        float r1 = x1 + w1 / 2;
        float r2 = x2 + w2 / 2;
        float right = r1 < r2 ? r1 : r2;
        return right - left;
    }

    protected static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1;
    protected static final int PIXEL_SIZE = 3;

    /**
     * Writes Image data into a {@code ByteBuffer}.
     */
    protected ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
//        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * BATCH_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE * PIXEL_SIZE);
//        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
//        int[] intValues = new int[INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel = 0;

        imgData.rewind();
        for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < INPUT_SIZE; ++j) {
                int pixelValue = intValues[i * INPUT_SIZE + j];
                if (isModelQuantized) {
                    // Quantized model
                    imgData.put((byte) ((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                    imgData.put((byte) ((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                    imgData.put((byte) (((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                } else { // Float model
                    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                }
            }
        }
        return imgData;
    }

    public ArrayList<Recognition> recognizeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer_ = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);

        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();

//        float[][][] outbuf = new float[1][output_box][labels.size() + 5];
        outData.rewind();
        outputMap.put(0, outData);
        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "mObjThresh: " + getObjThresh());

        Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
        tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) outputMap.get(0);
        byteBuffer.rewind();

        ArrayList<Recognition> detections = new ArrayList<Recognition>();

        float[][][] out = new float[1][output_box][numClass + 5];
        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "out[0] detect start");
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numClass + 5; ++j) {
                if (isModelQuantized){
                    out[0][i][j] = oup_scale * (((int) byteBuffer.get() & 0xFF) - oup_zero_point);
                }
                else {
                    out[0][i][j] = byteBuffer.getFloat();
                }
            }
            // Denormalize xywh
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                out[0][i][j] *= getInputSize();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i){
            final int offset = 0;
            final float confidence = out[0][i][4];
            int detectedClass = -1;
            float maxClass = 0;

            final float[] classes = new float[labels.size()];
            for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); ++c) {
                classes[c] = out[0][i][5 + c];
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); ++c) {
                if (classes[c] > maxClass) {
                    detectedClass = c;
                    maxClass = classes[c];
                }
            }

            final float confidenceInClass = maxClass * confidence;
            if (confidenceInClass > getObjThresh()) {
                final float xPos = out[0][i][0];
                final float yPos = out[0][i][1];

                final float w = out[0][i][2];
                final float h = out[0][i][3];
                Log.d("YoloV5Classifier",
                        Float.toString(xPos) + ',' + yPos + ',' + w + ',' + h);

                final RectF rect =
                        new RectF(
                                Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                                Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));
                detections.add(new Recognition("" + offset, labels.get(detectedClass),
                        confidenceInClass, rect, detectedClass));
            }
        }

        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "detect end");
        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = nms(detections);
//        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = detections;
        return recognitions;
    }

    public boolean checkInvalidateBox(float x, float y, float width, float height, float oriW, float oriH, int intputSize) {
        // (1) (x, y, w, h) --> (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
        float halfHeight = height / 2.0f;
        float halfWidth = width / 2.0f;

        float[] pred_coor = new float[]{x - halfWidth, y - halfHeight, x + halfWidth, y + halfHeight};

        // (2) (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) -> (xmin_org, ymin_org, xmax_org, ymax_org)
        float resize_ratioW = 1.0f * intputSize / oriW;
        float resize_ratioH = 1.0f * intputSize / oriH;

        float resize_ratio = resize_ratioW > resize_ratioH ? resize_ratioH : resize_ratioW; //min

        float dw = (intputSize - resize_ratio * oriW) / 2;
        float dh = (intputSize - resize_ratio * oriH) / 2;

        pred_coor[0] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[0] - dw) / resize_ratio;
        pred_coor[2] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[2] - dw) / resize_ratio;

        pred_coor[1] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[1] - dh) / resize_ratio;
        pred_coor[3] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[3] - dh) / resize_ratio;

        // (3) clip some boxes those are out of range
        pred_coor[0] = pred_coor[0] > 0 ? pred_coor[0] : 0;
        pred_coor[1] = pred_coor[1] > 0 ? pred_coor[1] : 0;

        pred_coor[2] = pred_coor[2] < (oriW - 1) ? pred_coor[2] : (oriW - 1);
        pred_coor[3] = pred_coor[3] < (oriH - 1) ? pred_coor[3] : (oriH - 1);

        if ((pred_coor[0] > pred_coor[2]) || (pred_coor[1] > pred_coor[3])) {
            pred_coor[0] = 0;
            pred_coor[1] = 0;
            pred_coor[2] = 0;
            pred_coor[3] = 0;
        }

        // (4) discard some invalid boxes
        float temp1 = pred_coor[2] - pred_coor[0];
        float temp2 = pred_coor[3] - pred_coor[1];
        float temp = temp1 * temp2;
        if (temp < 0) {
            Log.e("checkInvalidateBox", "temp < 0");
            return false;
        }
        if (Math.sqrt(temp) > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
            Log.e("checkInvalidateBox", "temp max");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it could be that you device doesn't support GPU delegate, // Check if device supports GPU delegate

val compatList = CompatibilityList()

val isSupported = compatList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice

Comment: I checked, GPU delegate is supported for my device. device is redmi note 7.

Comment: so did the function I mentioned returned true, or you just checked the device type online ?

Comment: i just checked online, its adreno 512 (gpu). i did'nt tried the function but i runned the tensorflow sample app on gpu and it works on my android device so i guess the problem is with the code.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience even if GPU delegate works on one device doesn't mean that it will work on all devices, that is because of different board and GPU. This is handled on TensorFlow part, and there are two things that I can think of:

1. If you are using a pre trained model  maybe its a good idea to open an issue on their [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)
2. You can try running another model architecture on GPU on the mobile/board of yours that is not working, and after you find the architecture that you can run on GPU, you can train that one.

And as an overall suggestion for the future its always good to check first if your device supports GPU delegate before using it, since the app (like in your case) can crash while another user uses different phone. You can do that like this:

```
val compatList = CompatibilityList() 
val isSupported = compatList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice
if (isSupported) {
    // Add GPU delegate
}
```